# cordova plugin's metadata value not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using `ngcordova` and `ionic` to develop one demo app.

But somehow i see `/www/cordova_plugins.js`  this file metadata values never updated,  and that is why i am having issues for social login.

```
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{}
```

above code stay same no matter if i add or remove plugin vice versa.

**Cordova version**

```
Dipeshs-Mac-mini:AppIonic Dipesh$ cordova -version
5.4.0
```

**Ionic version**

```
Dipeshs-Mac-mini:AppIonic Dipesh$ ionic -version
1.7.10
```

**Plugin i am trying**

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

But plugin seems working but somehow i got inappbrowser plugin not found but i have installed it.

And by debuging in deep i came to know that `var cordovaMetadata = cordova.require("cordova/plugin_list").metadata;` this code give empty array and that is reason plugin isn't working.

So if you guys have any idea share it with me so i can overcome this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading i found answer on my own.

Actually cordova new version might have some issues so downgraded cordova version to `5.3.3` and all seems working fine.